# RESTful login with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, authentication, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

How do I do RESTful sign-up and sign-in using devise in Ruby on Rails (I am using version 4)?

First of all, I could not find any documentation with regards to the parameters (e.g. email, password) that I should POST to the server.

EDIT:
Based on further investigation, it seems that RESTful login using json data (e.g. via AJAX) is not supported out of the box in the current version of devise. When I send a JSON request it responds with a HTML page instead of a JSON object. Does this mean that I need to create custom controller for handling user registration and login? If so, please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Most things are the same.  The main change is the switch to strong parameters.  To add your own strong parameters, put this in your application controller:

```
def configure_devise_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |u|
        u.permit(fields go here)
    end
end
```

Otherwise, its essentially the same procedure as in 3.  If there is something else you don't know how to do, please ask a more specific question.

Comment: Your question is different from your original.  You should create a new question - This is proper Stackoverflow procedure and it will also go out to more appropriate people (id recommend adding a json tag and possibly an 'mvc' or 'ruby gems' tag since your post deals with whether or not you should override a gem.  I don't know a great deal about json, but it is generally a VERY DANGEROUS idea to override devise with a custom controller.  You may be better off by adding a 'before_create' and/or a before_update to your user model.

Comment: Done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20319961/restful-login-with-devise-rails-4. Thanks